# jquery synchronous execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, synchronous

I am trying to get the resoution of a remote image.

```
function getMaxRes(url)
{
    var imgHeight=0;
     $("<img/>").attr("src", url).load(function(){
         s = {w:this.width, h:this.height};
         imgHeight =  this.height ;   
        console.log(imgHeight); // printed correctly

      }); 
     console.log(imgHeight); //prints 0

}
getMaxRes(< url to the image > )
```

I have tried using global variables. How can I make the function to return the image height.

Comment: Use a callback.  Don't make it synchronous.

Comment: Bind to the load event first, then set the src. but you must use the callback anyway. Also note that in jQuery 1.9+, `.load` does not bind a load event.